# Should I write my own GridView implementation?

Tags: .net, asp.net, gridview

I haven't worked with GridView too much and after poking around with it, find it to be more complex than I need but missing some very basic abilities that I would expect it to have.  No doubt its implementation makes sense given its 90% of the time purpose of being bound to a dataset especially when doing this declaratively, but I intend to bind it to an `IEnumerable<T>` in code.

What I need is the ability to do the following easily

- a) be bound to an `IEnumerable<T>` where the columns can be limited to only certain properties of type `T`
- b) be queried to return a collection of its rows where each row can have a cell looked up by the property that cell was bound to

basically something implementing the following interface would be nice

```
public interface IEasyGridBinder {
  void Bind<T>(IEnumerable<T> bindableObjects, params string[] propertiesToBind);
  IList<IDictionary<string, string>> Values {get;}
}
```

So to get this, should I write my own custom EasyGridBinder that inherits from GridView and implements this interface or is there a really simple way to do these things that I am just unfamiliar with?

P.S. Bonus points if I can write something like

```
myGrid.Bind(myEntities, e=>{e.Id; e.Name; e.Customer.Name;});
```

But I suppose I can figure that out myself after reading up on expressions

**Follow-up question:** Is there no way to get the original data that was input into the gridview and has not been converted to html?  If a field received as input an empty string the cell seems to contain " " so is there no way to distinguish between an input of an empty string and a space?  If this is indeed the case then I probably WILL end up re-implementing most of GridView's functionality.

Comment: I am actually kind of shocked that no one has a good solution for this problem.  I guess I've got some work ahead of me tonight, this has been blocking my demo for a few days.  I'll probably release it on google code later

Answer (score 2):

[LinqDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb547113.aspx) allows you to specify your object as the backing store for the data source.  You'd then bind the GridView to that datasource.  It's a bit more declaration in the .aspx, but it's less code to maintain later as feature bloat brings you closer and closer to reimplementing GridView.

Comment: Not bad, but strings everywhere!  There goes refactoring support.

Comment: I mean is it just me, or are these operations that I'm discussing things that should be quite standard to want out of a GridView?  Principle of least astonishment - fail

Comment: In my experience, MS's way of attacking these kinds of problems is almost never the least-astonishing way to do things, but in the end it 's the way that (1) works best with what's already there (2) ends up being what I actually wanted, rather than what I thought I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the GridViews AutoGenerateColumns property to false it will only generated the columns you specify. You do that by creating BoundFields and adding them to the Gridview Columns collection.

```
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

BoundField bf = new BoundField();
bf.DataField = "Id";
bf.HeaderText = "ID";
gv.Columns.Add(bf);

BoundField bf = new BoundField();
bf.DataField = "Name";
bf.HeaderText = "Name";
gv.Columns.Add(bf);

BoundField bf = new BoundField();
bf.DataField = "Customer.Name";
bf.HeaderText = "Customer Name";
gv.Columns.Add(bf);

gv.DataSource = IEnumerable<T>;
gv.DataBind();
```

I had written this explanation up in the comments but figured I'd move it out to where it was more visible and add a code example:

To make the above dynamic create a GridViewDisplayAttribute class which inherits from Attribute. Give GridViewDisplayAttribute a HeaderText property. Decorate the properties of  of T specifying HeaderText. By iterating the properties of T creating BoundFields for each decorated property utilizing HeaderText.

Quick untested code example:

```
using System;
public class GridViewDisplayAttribute : Attribute
{
public GridViewDisplayAttribute(string headerText)
{
        HeaderText = headerText;
}
    public readonly bool HeaderText;
}
```

---

```
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

Type t = <T>.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] pis = t.GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo pi in pis)
{
    GridViewDisplayAttribute[] gvdaArray = pi.GetCustomAttributes(
        typeof(GridViewDisplayAttribute), true);

    foreach (GridViewDisplayAttribute gvda in gvdaArray)
    {
        BoundField bf = new BoundField();
        bf.DataField = pi.Name;
        bf.HeaderText = gvda.HeaderText;
    }

    gv.Columns.Add(bf);
}

gv.DataSource = IEnumerable<T>;
gv.DataBind();
```

Comment: Hmm, that will be pretty helpful, I wasn't having much luck with DataKeyNames.  Thanks!

Comment: To make dynamic create a GridViewDisplayAttribute : Attribute class. Giving GridViewDisplayAttribute a HeaderText property would allow you to decorate the properties of T specifying HeaderText. By iterating the properties of T creating BoundFields for each decorated property utilizing HeaderText.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using extension methods to add the required behavior.  The only downside  to that is that you can't add "Values" as a property.

Comment: Yeah, but I only want to write an extension if there's a really simple way of doing these things.  If there isn't ... say more than three lines, I might as well subclass since I'm probably going to have to do other things as well.

Comment: It will definitely be more than 3 lines.  The benefit of using the extension method, though, is that you don't have to change any existing ASPX markup to replace "GridView" with "EasyGridBinder".

Comment: Yeah, this is what I started with but I have a rule that extension methods should be nothing more than convenience shortcuts, any real behavior there tends to be a codesmell.